# ansible: sudo and change user

Tags: linux, ansible

Could you please advise how

```
sudo su - userb
```

translates into ansible ?

More specifically, I would like to login to linux server X as `usera` then become `userb` (with the command above), and then execute all the tasks defined in the playbook as `userb`

The following are configuration options in `ansible.cfg`:

```
sudo_user      = root
#ask_sudo_pass = True
#ask_pass      = True
#remote_user = root
#become=True
#become_method=sudo
#become_user=root
#become_ask_pass=False
```

An example task would be:

```
- name: "Create the version directory of app"
        remote_user: userb
        file: path="{{ app_dir }}/{{ app_version }}" state=directory owner=userb group=xxx
```

EDIT: please note that no sudo password is provided in order to become `userb`

```
usera@serverX:~> sudo su - userb
Last login: Fri Nov 17 15:46:48 CET 2017 on pts/1
-bash-4.2$
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to run any particular tasks as a different user, do the following:

```
- name: "Create the version directory of app"
        file: path="{{ app_dir }}/{{ app_version }}" state=directory owner=userb group=userb
        become: yes
        become_user: userb
```

Reference: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/become.html

Oh and you should change `remote_user` to the user who you want to log into the server with and that should probably be in the inventory file.

Comment: `{"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "There was an issue creating /u01/appl/netopsapp/pmacct as requested: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/u01/appl/netopsapp/pmacct'", "path": "/u01/appl/netopsapp/pmacct/1.7.1", "state": "absent"}`

Comment: `ls -salt
total 0
0 drwxr-xr-x 2 pmacctapp netopsapp  6 Nov 17 16:39 .
0 drwxr-xr-x 3 pmacctapp netopsapp 23 Nov 13 12:37 ..`

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Comment: unfortunately, this is not working. `sudo: a password is required` what i forgot to mention is what when doing `sudo su - userb` it is done without providing a password, see "edit"

Comment: Try to add your user that you login with (become user) to the **sudoers** file https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos

Answer (score 0):

I´ve review a lot of forums about that this is my solution
I hope its usefull for you

- name: Install httpd

  hosts:

  - webserver

  become: true

  become_user: usera

  become_method: sudo

  become_flags: 'su - userbsuperuser'

  tasks:

  - action: ping
  - name: List all services in Linux

    ansible.builtin.service_facts:
  - name: Print Services in linux

    ansible.builtin.debug:

    var: ansible_facts.services

Comment: You should add YAML lines in a code block to not mess up the syntax